# Can I completely reset my Mac while it is attached to Time Machine? (I don't want to restore from a backup, just keep the backup)

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore

For various reasons, I want to completely reset my iMac and reinstall everything from the ground up (that's easier than cleaning up by now).

I have Time Machine running and I wanted to ask if all my backups (on an external HDD) are going to be okay after erasing the internal disk and reinstalling macOS.

Will it still work and let me access my old backups while continuing to back up the new system?

I'm 99% sure it does but I've never done it and don't want to actually lose anything.